# VS Code gives import error but the script works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing my first script in python and VS Code marks me errors, but the script works fine.

The error are like this:

```
from pyautogui import screenshot
```

and marks screenshot in red and pyautogui in blue and gives this error:

> "screenshot" is unknown import symbolPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

Is anything wrong since this works, or is there a way to take the warning?

I tried using the quickfix suggestion

```
 # type: ignore # type: ignorefrom requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession, HTMLSession
```

But doesn't do anything.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with Python 3.11.1, VSCode 1.74.2, Pylance 2023.1.10 and PyAutoGUI 0.9.53

Comment: Although my Pylance did not prompt an error, it did not recognize the screenshot () method. There is [a similar problem](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/746) in github, but no one answered. For the problem itself, my Pylance has no red line and error report. You can try to upgrade the library: `pip uninstall pyautogui` and `pip install pyautogui`, or you can also upgrade Pylance in the extension store.